# Using eigenvectors as a basis for space

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following matrix

$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0\\a&0&0&0\\0&b&0&0\\0&0&c&0\end{bmatrix}$

Which $a,b,c$ are real numbers

What conditions are required for $a,b,c$ such that $\mathbb{R}^4$ has a basis made of A eigenvectors?

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $X^4$, so the only eigenvalue is $0$.

If $A$ is diagonalizable then, it means that $A=0$, so $a=b=c=0$.

Conversely, if $a=b=c=0$, all vectors are eigenvectors, so of course you can find a basis made of eigenvectors.

So the necessary and sufficient condition is that $a=b=c=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$\lambda = 0$ is the only eigenvalue (it has algebraic multiplicity 4). The only way the system $Av = 0$ has 4 degrees of freedom is if $A=0$, i.e. $a=b=c=0$.